# Referencing a nested structure in C

Tags: c, data-structures

So, basically, I have two different structures defined in two different .h files (vcard.h and bst.h), both of which are included in the current file. Here are the structure definitions:

```
struct bst {
  vcard *c;
  bst *lsub;
  bst *rsub;
};

struct vcard {
  char *cnet;
  char *email;
  char *fname;
  char *lname;
  char *tel;
};
```

In my bst insert function, i am trying to run the following:

```
bst *bst_insert(bst *t, vcard *c){

    if (strcmp(c->cnet, t->c.cnet) > 0){
    ...
    }
}
```

The compiler is spitting back the following error:

"bst.c:28: error: request for member ‘cnet’ in something not a structure or union"

Am I calling t->c.cnet incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

c is a pointer, you need t->c->cnet

Comment: Thanks Gary! For some reason, I thought that the second arrow was supposed to be a dot. I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

Should be `t->c->cnet` because c is a pointer to a `vcard`

Answer (score 0):

Just a side answer, you can also use the `.` operator to access a member of a pointer to a structure. You just have to dereference the pointer first with parenthesis due to predecence then you may access the member like so `t->(*c).cnet`. The `->` notation was created as a shorthand way of doing this.